# How to resolve 422 Unprocessable Entity issue in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

One of the https POST request returns Response code:422 and Response message:Unprocessable Entity everytime I run my script using JMeter. Can some one let me know how to resolve this error and get a 200 OK message.

Request Body and Request Headers doesn't show any errors but the request throws 422 Unprocessable Entity response.

Note: The same request returns 200 Success response and throws 422 Unprocessable Entity response sometimes if I run the request without making any changes.

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTTP Status Code 422 description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422)

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 422 Unprocessable Entity response status code indicates that the server understands the content type of the request entity, and the syntax of the request entity is correct, **but it was unable to process the contained instructions.**

it means that the [Content-Type header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) is correct and the request body is syntactically correct as well (i.e. well-formed JSON or XML) but the server is not able to process the body because semantics is wrong

So you need to double check the request body and ensure that JMeter is sending what it is supposed to be sending.

You can check what JMeter is sending using [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree), if you're running the test in non-GUI mode you will need to take some extra steps in order to [configure JMeter to save request and response data](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-data-in-jmeter) like amending [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) or adding a separate [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html)

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri for your response and I just edited my question with the comment below as I forgot to mention this earlier when posted my question:

"
The same request returns 200 Success response and throws 422 Unprocessable Entity response sometimes if I run the request without making any changes."